# fetch data from mysql and use it in another form

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, forms

This php code creates a table  which has a "book" button against each row.

I want to get the value of "phase" and "site" from the row where "book" is clicked into another form(in "restricted.php") to book the site. (At the moment  all the rows get submitted on click of book)

```
<?php 
    $phase=$_GET["q"];
    $sql ="select id, phase,size, facing, sply, status from plot where status='avail' and phase='$phase'";
    $ret=mysql_query($sql, $connect);

    echo "<form action='restricted.php' method='get'>";

    echo"<div style='overflow-y:scroll;height:200px;float:left;' ><table border=1 >
    <tr>
    <td>select </td><td>phase</td> <td>site no.</td> <td>plot-size</td> <td>face</td> <td>sply</td> <td>status</td>
    </tr>" ;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($ret, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {

        echo "<tr>".
            "<td><input type='submit' name='book' value='book' onClick=\"whichForm('send_to_one');\" /></td>".
            "<td><input type='text' value=\"{$row['phase']}\" name='phase' size='3' readonly />  </td>".
             "<td><input type='text' value=\"{$row['id']}\" name='site' size='4' readonly /></td>".
             "<td> {$row['size']} </td>".
             "<td> {$row['facing']} </td>".
             "<td>{$row['sply']} </td> ".
             "<td>{$row['status']} </td> ".
             "</tr>";   

    } 
    echo "</table></div>";

    mysql_close($connect);

    ?>
```

Comment: make a class and acces the functions of the class right on top of the page where you want the data!!!basic php,mysql..what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: no need to take onclick function

Comment: OPUS, i am not able to access the value of "phase" and "site" for the row "book" was clicked, once "book" is clicked for any row, "phase" and "site" values from all the rows are passed in "get"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to move your form tag in while loop and close it with in the loop so that you can have different form for different row and on submit button it will submit the related form only.

Answer (score 1):

You execute the function whichForm() when you click on the button. In that function you can add the variables phase and site.

Something like this:

```
echo "<td><input type='submit' name='book' value='book' onClick=\"whichForm('send_to_one', '{$row['phase']}', '{$row['site']}');\" /></td>";
```

/edit: change your code to something like this. It's not the most beautiful solution for readability, but it should work.

```
<?php 
    $phase=$_GET["q"];
    $sql ="select id, phase,size, facing, sply, status from plot where status='avail' and phase='$phase'";
    $ret=mysql_query($sql, $connect);

    echo"<div style='overflow-y:scroll;height:200px;float:left;' ><table border=1 >
    <tr>
    <td>select </td><td>phase</td> <td>site no.</td> <td>plot-size</td> <td>face</td> <td>sply</td> <td>status</td>
    </tr>" ;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($ret, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {

        echo "<tr>".
            "<form action='restricted.php' method='post'>".
            "<td><input type='submit' name='book' value='book' onClick=\"whichForm('send_to_one');\" /></td>".
            "<td><input type='text' value=\"{$row['phase']}\" name='phase' size='3' readonly />  </td>".
             "<td><input type='text' value=\"{$row['id']}\" name='site' size='4' readonly /></td>".
             "<td> {$row['size']} </td>".
             "<td> {$row['facing']} </td>".
             "<td>{$row['sply']} </td> ".
             "<td>{$row['status']} </td> ".
             "<input type='hidden' name='phase' value='{$row['phase']}'>".
             "<input type='hidden' name='site' value='{$row['site']}'>".
             "</form>".
             "</tr>";   

    } 
    echo "</table></div>";

    mysql_close($connect);

    ?>
```

In your restricted.php you can access the values with:

```
$_POST['site'];
$_POST['phase'];
```

Comment: Ivo Geersen , how do i access this phase and site values to be put in another form.

Comment: I don't completely understand your question, but you want to go to another form when you click on book? This can be done in several ways If you want to work with your existing function (whichForm()), you have to open that form with javascript and you can pass the variables in the URL. Better would be to create a form for each row, place the phase and site in hidden fields in each row, and get them from the $_POST in your restricted.php (btw, pick form method=post then)